# how delete a table frequently can effect on query from that?

Tags: sql, oracle

I should delete a table and insert into it frequently on oracle database. I find out that query from the table goes slowly. I guess deleting from a table in frequently manner is responsible. do you have any idea about that?

Comment: what about truncating the table?

Comment: How many inserts and deletes are we talking about? What is "frequent"? There are a *LOT* of other more likely reasons that query performance could be bad. What makes you think table DML is responsible? Please post a reproducible example, including DDL for your table, any indexes, and SQL and an explain plan for your  slow query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5193536/nbk   yes truncate is a second plan but i need delete-insert combination.

Comment: I want to delete or insert more than 20 millions records everyday.  the query works fast in first days, but if I use delete-insert combination daily the query goes slowly over time. target table (you call that table_x) has more than 1 billion records.

I use these statements:

```
delete some records from table_x;
insert some records into table_x;

select sum(x),y,z from table_x partition(p54) group by y,z;

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of possible causes here

1. Could be a poor execution plan because the database thinks you have "n" whereas you in reality have "m" rows now due to the DML activity
2. Could be inefficient full scans because the high water mark is higher than it needs to be
3. Could be delayed block cleanout, where your queries have to clean up "mess" left around by the DML
4. Could be just overall server load.  Queries are fine in isolation, DML is fine in isolation, but the combination of the two is pushing the resources over the top.

Ideally a trace or AWR report on the system would be useful to track down what is happening

Comment: Thank you for your answer in advance. I guess deleting (in a frequently manner) causes inefficient data distribution in database blocks and this increases I/O where I use a select query (as you remembered in reason 2).
I should use "trunacte" and change the code.

Comment: Or perhaps an occasional "alter table shrink space" or "alter table move online" might be all that is needed.....*if* it was reason 2

Comment: yes shrink and move online work. indeed, these commands fill free space in blocks and reduce I/O.